# Get kernel root dir in Twig template with Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig, symfony-http-kernel

I need to get kernel.root_dir in my twig template, I found solutions [here](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/symfony2-global-variables-twig/), but it does not work. I get error about non existing method Kernel in [this class](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/GlobalVariables.html#method_getEnvironment). Realy in GlobalVariables class method getKernel() not exists. So how I can get root_dir in twig template.

(P.S. No I cant get it form controller, and no I cant get it as container parameters)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest you to add a global variable in your config.yml:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        kernelRootDir: "%kernel.root_dir%"
```

Then, use `{{ kernelRootDir }}` in your views.

Comment: Yes, this nice solution, but I dont want to tie my app to configuration.

Comment: You can also create globals using an extension. But this is quite less friendly than the config file.

Comment: Okey, if is single proper way I will axcept your answer. Thanks for help man!)

Comment: Be aware that `%kernel.root_dir%` must be quoted nowadays.

Comment: Thanks, edited. Do not hesitate to edit such changes yourself next time :) cheers

Answer (score 2):

In newer Symfony versions the solution is similar, but the parameter `kernel.root_dir` has been removed in version [5.0](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3703f1440eba8d704b02f427c781bbcb6e1ada49/UPGRADE-5.0.md) and the config file for twig is located elsewhere.

Now you can use the `kernel.project_dir` parameter, which resolves to the projct's root dir (not the kernel's root dir). This is usually the directory where your `composer.json` is located.

```yaml
twig:
    globals:
        kernelProjectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

Then use `{{ kernelProjectDir }}` in your templates.